# Flyway Unable to Use Snowflake JDBC

Tags: java, jdbc, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, flyway

I am trying to use the Snowflake JDBC Driver with Flyway. I am on Flyway Core Version `0.5.1` and have the snowflake jdbc driver version `3.12.17` installed. When debugging, I can connect to Snowflake manually with:

```
DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);
```

But when I try and set the Flyway data source like this:

```
flyway.setDataSource(DB_URL, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);
```

I get the following error:

```
Unable to autodetect JDBC driver for url: jdbc:snowflake://***.snowflakecomputing.com/?db=***&warehouse=COMPUTE_WH
```

I've tried setting the driver property manually:

```
Properties flywayProperties = new Properties();
flywayProperties.put("driver", "net.snowflake.client.jdbc.SnowflakeDriver");
flyway.setDataSource(DB_URL, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);
```

But unfortunately that didn't work either.

What am I doing wrong? How can I tell Flyway about my Snowflake JDBC Driver?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nevermind I just updated my Flyway to the latest (7.x) and it works fine. That's my recommendation to anyone in this situation. Just upgrade.